# MySQL++ and AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql++

Use to work with a MySQL + + (library for C + +)

The database has some fields for which you AUTO_INCREMENT.
How to know what value will these fields when inserting a new row to the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `mysql_insert_id()` C API function to retieve the auto-increment value after an insert.
See also [MySql Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 9):

While stacker's answer will work, MySQL++ wraps that function as [SimpleResult::insert_id()](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/refman/classmysqlpp_1_1SimpleResult.html#c7493c4b03818e8a88b69abc987286b6). Example:

```
Query q = conn.query();
q.insert(something);
if (SimpleResult res = q.execute()) {
    cout << "Auto-increment value: " << res.insert_id() << endl;
}
```